# Why do these two different ways of constructing an array produce different behaviors?

Tags: arrays, julia

When I construct a 2 element array in two different ways(e.g. `a` and `b`, I get two different results when I add an element to one of the inner arrays. This also happens with `append!`. Based on the output after constructing each, I'd expect them to be exactly the same?

```
julia> a = [[],[]]
2-element Array{Array{Any,1},1}:
 Any[]
 Any[]

julia> push!(a[1],1.0)
1-element Array{Any,1}:
 1.0

julia> a
2-element Array{Array{Any,1},1}:
 Any[1.0]
 Any[]

julia> b = fill([],2)
2-element Array{Array{Any,1},1}:
 Any[]
 Any[]

julia> push!(b[1],1.0)
1-element Array{Any,1}:
 1.0

julia> b
2-element Array{Array{Any,1},1}:
 Any[1.0]
 Any[1.0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fill` will create an array initialized with n copies (shallow) of the *same* object, so that `b[1]` === `b[2]`, and when you update `b[1]`, you're updating the same object that's also pointed to in `b[2]`.

Comment: Is there a similar function which fills with the _value_ rather than the reference?

Comment: `a = [[] for _ in 1:10]` initialises an empty array for each element in the array comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the following examples.
Hopefully the behavior is as you expect.

#### Input[1]:

```
a_1 = []
a_2 = []
a = [a_1, a_2]
push!(a_1, 1.0)
@show a_1 
@show a
```

Output[1]:

```
a_1 = Any[1.0]
a = Array{Any,1}[Any[1.0],Any[]]
```

#### Input[2]

```
push!(a[1], 2.0)
@show a_1 #Guess what this shows
@show a
```

Output[2]:

```
a_1 = Any[1.0,2.0]
a = Array{Any,1}[Any[1.0,2.0],Any[]]
```

---

#### Input[3]:

```
b_n = []
b = fill(b_n, 2)
push!(b_n, 1.0)
@show b_n 
@show b
```

Output[3]:

```
b_n = Any[1.0]
b = Array{Any,1}[Any[1.0],Any[1.0]]
```

#### Input[4]:

```
push!(b[1], 2.0)
@show b_n #Guess what this shows
@show b
```

Output[4]

```
b_n = Any[1.0,2.0]
b = Array{Any,1}[Any[1.0,2.0],Any[1.0,2.0]]
```

#### Input[5]:

```
c_n = []
c = [c_n, c_n]
push!(c_n, 1.0)
@show c_n 
@show c
```

Output[5]:

```
c_n = Any[1.0]
c = Array{Any,1}[Any[1.0],Any[1.0]]
```

#### Input[6]:

```
push!(c[1], 2.0)
@show c_n 
@show c
```

Output[6]:

```
c_n = Any[1.0,2.0]
c = Array{Any,1}[Any[1.0,2.0],Any[1.0,2.0]]
```

---

So Input[1] is the same as your `a`, and Input[3] is the same as your `b`

Each time you put a `[]` you construct a new `Vector`.

So in the first case: `a=[[],[]]` creates a vector containing two new vectors which I call `a_1` and `a_2` in Input[1]

In the second case: `b=fill([],2]` creates a vector, which  I call `b_n` in Input[3], and then it fills an vector of length 2, with that vector `b_n`.
This it equivelent to the example in Input[3] (with `c`). 
I might as well have said: `[b_n, b_n]` as said `fill(b_n,2)`

So it references to the same vector at each position. So changing one, changes the both.