# How to fill an array with a given value (not object reference)?

Tags: arrays, julia

As a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41072991/why-do-these-two-different-ways-of-constructing-an-array-produce-different-behav), how can you create an array filled with *copies* rather than *references* in Julia?

To use an example, how to create a function like `fill` that behaves like `a` when modifying elements of the array?

```
julia> a = [[],[]]
2-element Array{Array{Any,1},1}:
 Any[]
 Any[]

julia> push!(a[1],1.0)
1-element Array{Any,1}:
 1.0

julia> a
2-element Array{Array{Any,1},1}:
 Any[1.0]
 Any[]

julia> b = fill([],2)
2-element Array{Array{Any,1},1}:
 Any[]
 Any[]

julia> push!(b[1],1.0)
1-element Array{Any,1}:
 1.0

julia> b
2-element Array{Array{Any,1},1}:
 Any[1.0]
 Any[1.0]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comprehension, could help:

```
julia> a=[[] for i=1:4]
4-element Array{Array{Any,1},1}:
 Any[]
 Any[]
 Any[]
 Any[]

julia> push!(a[1],1)
1-element Array{Any,1}:
 1

julia> a
4-element Array{Array{Any,1},1}:
 Any[1]
 Any[]
 Any[]
 Any[]
```